# Read mock data (stubs) in UITest from a local storage to iPhone (real device not a simulator)

Tags: swift, iphone, mocking, xcuitest

Is there a way to read the Mock data which contains the Json files from the real iPhone during the UITest using XCUITest?

Mock data (Stubs) files are bundled as part of the XCTestRunner app but the iPhone is not able to read it from there. I also tried reading from the host storage but still no luck.

The above steps works fine when running on a simulator.